# How to extract y-axis value on R plot?

Tags: r

[image]

Hi all, I have this plot above. I want to extract the y-axis value (cumulative hazard %) to find the hazard at the END of the follow-up period between smokers and non-smokers.
Here is my code that I used to create the plot:

```
survmod1 <- survfit(Surv(timedth, death)~cursmoke, data=frmgham_recoded,
                    conf.type="log-log") #force confidence intervals to be bounded between 0 and 1

plot(survmod1, 
     main="Kaplan-Meier Failure Estimates by smoking status",
     xlab="Time (days)", ylab="Cumulative Hazard", 
     fun="event", #transforms data into failure event function, plots the complement
     bty="l", col=c("darkblue","darkorange"))
         
legend("bottomright",legend=c("no","yes"),
       lty=1, lwd=2, 
       col=c("darkblue","darkorange"),
       cex=0.8,bty="o")
```

Comment: Hey Natasha! What packages are the functions 'survfit' and 'Surv' from? Listing those could help others answer your question.

Comment: You cannot extract the values from the plot since base R plot functions return `NULL`, there's nothing to extract from it.

Comment: Library(survival)!

Comment: something like `with(survmod1, tapply(1 - surv, rep(names(strata), strata), tail, 1))` should work

Comment: or `broom::tidy(survmod1)` will get you a data frame to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: This should give you  `time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI`. You could tweak the times sequence as you need.

```
library(survival) 
library(survminer)
summary(survmod1, times = seq(0, 8000, 2000))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you survfit object contains the cumulative hazard data already.
Try `survmod1$cumhaz` to get these data.